# How can I select records from a table where unixtime(integer) column contains the current date without considering the time?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, timestamp, android-sqlite

I'm having a table with the following fields in Android SQLite database.

[image]

In this, due_date column is INTEGER, i just want the records which **matches today's date(current date)** alone in due_date **without considering time**.

For example: If I have 3 values matching with current date, I **need** to return **all 3 rows**

> Note: In my case, have to compare with current date not with current
> timestamp but my column type was **INTEGER having unix-epoch value**.
> My unix-epoch example is "**1526565900000**".

I have tried:

```
 date('now', 'start of day') // not working

 date('now','localtime','start of day') // not working

select strftime('%d', date('now')), name, due_date from task group by due_date;
```

this too not working for my requirement.

> Finally as per the comments below i **changed** all my datetime and
> **timestamp** column into **INTEGER** to store as **unix-epoch** value before that all my column were in timestamp.

Comment: You must store the values in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) in the database.

Comment: This is going to be a headache for you.  Please store your timestamps in an ISO format.

Comment: @CL. - thanks for your reply, timestamp format will not be supported by android-sqlite?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your reply, is it fine to store in datetime type of android-sqlite?

Comment: @Shiva There is **no** datetime type in SQLite.  All date/time information is stored as plain text.  This is why using an ISO format is so critical.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay i understand, can i get any reference link to store the values in iso format please....?

Comment: @Shiva CL already gave you a link in the very first comment.  Did you bother to read it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Just now that page loaded and I understand that but while creating a table i have to define the type of column right, for that what i have to give other than datetime/timestamp?

Comment: Use `TEXT`.  Sounds crazy, but that's how SQLite works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, need to use text and while inserting i have to format it like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS" this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170744/discussion-between-shiva-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: see [MediaColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns) for example and check `DATE_*` columns - this is a common way how datetime fields are handled in android

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if i use text as column type then how will i filter the data using query?

Comment: did you check `MediaColumns#DATE_ADDED` / `MediaColumns#DATE_MODIFIED` columns and how they store timestamp values?

Comment: @pskink i read this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns) but i can't understand.

Comment: this is the third [format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) as CL pointed in his first comment: *"INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC."*

Comment: okay, so i have create the column as INTEGER and can insert the values like "1525937612" format as mentioned in this [link](https://www.epochconverter.com/), i will do it but how extract the data after inserting ? that's my main question.

Comment: `android.text.format.DateUtils` for example, you can also use raw `java.util.Date` and `java.text.DateFormat` objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170750/discussion-between-shiva-and-pskink).

Comment: By "today’s date", what time zone do you mean? UTC? Some other zone such as `Europe/Berlin` or `Asia/Kolkata`? For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** First i changed the column type to int as @CL [mentioned](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) where it was declared as datetime and timestamp before.

**Step 2:** Then inserted all the datetime values in seconds(which is 10 digit) as @pskink said in comments.

**Step 3:** To get start and end value of current date in seconds i used the following java code.

```
//getCurrentDateTimeInMilliseconds
    public void getCurrentDateTimeInMilliseconds() {
        Date todayStart = new Date();
        Date todayEnd = new Date();

        todayStart.setHours(0);
        todayStart.setMinutes(0);
        todayStart.setSeconds(0);
        todayEnd.setHours(23);
        todayEnd.setMinutes(59);
        todayEnd.setSeconds(59);
        long endTime = todayEnd.getTime();
    }
```

using this you can get the start and end value of current day like this

```
todayStart.getTime()
```

it will return value in milliseconds which is 13 digit value to convert this to seconds just divide by 1000 like this,

```
long startDateInSeconds = todayStart.getTime/1000;
long startDateInSeconds = todayEnd.getTime/1000;
```

and use these values in the sqlite query based on requirement in my case the query will be as follows:

```
String query = "select * from task where due_date>" + startDateInSeconds + " and due_date<" + startDateInSeconds;
```

and then pass the query in the method of databasehelper class like this,

Cursor cursor = databasehelper.getData(query);

in DatabaseHelper.java(which should extends SQLiteOpenHelper class) file do the following code:

```
public Cursor getData(String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
```

finally nailed it with the help of [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink), thanks for your comments helped me a lot.

Data stored like this in my db.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(                        // Generally best to use Prepared Statement, to avoid SQL Injection risk.
    1 ,                                               // Specify which placeholder `?` in your SQL statement.
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine today’s date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain continent/region (a time zone).
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone. Not always 00:00:00.
    .toInstant()                                      // Adjust that first moment of the day in that zone to the wall-clock-time of UTC.
    .getEpochSecond()                                 // Get a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

> In this, due_date column is INTEGER, i just want the records which matches today's date(current date) alone in due_date without considering time.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

### Epoch seconds

We need to translate that date to a number, the count of seconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

To do that, we need to get the first moment of the day. Let *java.time* determine that first moment. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Specify a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

We must adjust into UTC from our zone. Easiest way to do this is to extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). The `Instant` class is always in UTC by default.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from our zone to UTC.
```

Get the number of seconds since epoch.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

As a shortcut, we could have asked for seconds-from-epoch directly from the `ZonedDateTime` class. But I wanted to make clear that we are working adjusting from a particular time zone to UTC.

```
long startSecondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond() ;  // Shortcut for adjusting from time zone to UTC, and then getting count of seconds since epoch.
```

We also need the ending of our time range, to find all records whose date is today’s date. We will use the first moment of the following day. This follows the usual practice of Half-Open definition of a span of time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
long stopSecondsSinceEpoch = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toEpochSecond() ;
```

### SQL

Now we are ready for the SQL statement. Generally best to make a habit of using a prepared statement.

```
String sql = "SELECT when FROM tbl WHERE when >= ? AND when < ? ; " ;
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , startSecondsSinceEpoch ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stopSecondsSinceEpoch ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM your table name where due_date BETWEEN date('now') AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', due_date)
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i need to extract the value for column due_date, how to do for that?

Comment: sorry, it's not working and i changed all my column into Integer to store unix epoch time which is worked fine but still not yet get the query for my requirement, thanks.

Comment: @pskink first thanks four idea, it pushed me to learn some interesting concepts, actually  don't know the query to get the due_date records which matching with today's date for Integer(unix_epoch) value, pls help me in this.

Comment: @pskink tried this **"select * from task where due_date>1525910400 and due_date<1525996800;"** 
0 rows returned from: select * from task where due_date>1525910400 and due_date<1525996800; (took 1ms)

Comment: @Shiva the query is ok, your data in sql db is not ok